# Why TCP client can not connect to TCP server sometimes after TCP server restart?

Tags: c, linux, tcpserver

I just wrote a TCP server and it worked fine most of the time.
But if I kill it manually and restart it immediately, TCP client could not connect to it sometimes.
Then if I kill it and restart it again, it will be okay again.
I really want to know why and I had try to modify `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle` and `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse`. But it didn't work.

Comment: Most likely there's a bug in the server, mishandling the case where it's unable to open the port immediately on startup and not seeting SO_REUSEPORT. But we can't debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has indeed to do with the way sockets are set to be re-used.

Try initializing your socket in this way:

```
int reuse_addr = 1;
int listener_socket = 0;

listener_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //get socket handle
if (listener_socket < 0)
{
  //Handle error
}

//Set the socket reusable
setsockopt(listener_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse_addr, sizeof(int));
```

Variable `reuse_addr` is `1` to identify that we want to **enable** a particular option (`0` will disable).

The `SOL_SOCKET` keyword means that you want to set socket level setting/option, it will be protocol independent. We set `SO_REUSEADDR`, you can read more about it here: http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml

Other available settings, you can check from here: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_352.html

Comment: I wonder if there is way to change system configurations and enable re-used by default.

Comment: Your system will have other programs with sockets as well, so changing some global settings might have strange effects on system operation - I think it is better to just stick to control fully your own code